# Apache Flex 4.14.1 BorderContainer Radius only applies in Debugger

Tags: css, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, apache-spark

**What To Achieve** 
 
I'm trying to apply a rounded corner to an Image retrieved from a URL by using a BorderContainer (SPARK).

**The Problem**
The Radius attribute of the BorderContainer component is only being applied when running the code from my debugger, running it elsewhere does simply not apply the radius to the bitmap image.

**Code Example**

```
<s:BitmapImage id="img"  width="60"  height="60" source="{data.IconURL}" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high">
  <s:mask>
    <s:BorderContainer id="bmpMask" cornerRadius="15" width="60" height="60" borderVisible="true" />
  </s:mask>
</s:BitmapImage>
```

**Image Examples**
1. As it should be (And is in the debugger only): 
[image]

As it is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Full working example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <s:BitmapImage source="https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5wu759l1tkiw2b/archer.jpg?dl=1" 
                   height="100" width="100" maskType="alpha">
        <s:mask>
            <s:BorderContainer id="bmpMask" cornerRadius="15" width="60" height="60" 
                               borderVisible="true"/>
        </s:mask>
    </s:BitmapImage>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: This has the exact same result

Comment: Have you tried running it from outside your debugger? e.g. using IIS?